# How to align toast in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to change position of Toast in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android)

Is there any method to align toast message in application.By default it always appears at the bottom of application.
i did it like this...
Toast.makeText(this, "hello !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void setGravity(int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset)
```

Comment: Hi i did like this and now its working fine.
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, 40, 60);
toast.show();

Answer (score 5):

[Toast.setGravity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setGravity%28int,%20int,%20int%29)