# How to change position of Toast in Android?

Tags: android, toast

When I use `Toast` to display some popup text on the screen, it displays the text a little bit above the bottom of the screen, which is the default position.

Now I want to display it in the middle of the screen or somewhere according to my choice.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 452, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html),

> **Positioning your Toast**
>
> A standard toast notification appears near the bottom of the screen,
>   centered horizontally. You can change this position with the
>   `setGravity(int, int, int)` method. This accepts three parameters: a
>   `Gravity` constant, an `x-position` offset, and a `y-position` offset.
>
> For example, if you decide that the toast should appear in the
>   top-left corner, you can set the gravity like this:
>
> ```
> toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
> ```
>
> If you want to nudge the position to the right, increase the value of
>   the second parameter. To nudge it down, increase the value of the last
>   parameter.

Comment: what are the integer values there?  Are they dpi? or what is the max?

Comment: Might be pointing out the obvious, but `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` will put the toast in the middle of the screen.

Comment: x and y offset are in pixel, so the maximum is your display width / height.

Comment: @Pentium10 The docs state that the offsets are in pixels. Should I assume that these are "px" units, as opposed to "dp" units?

Comment: My toast messages on my new galaxy s6 show in 2 different positions. first in the left horizontal center vertical and then moves down to center horizontal, bottom vertical. this effect does not happen on any of my older test devices. I display each message twice in row since any screen taps kill the first toast right away.,

Comment: I've found Gravity.NO_GRAVITY does not actually set the toast to the default position of 1/4 to 1/3 up from the bottom, it sets to the center just like Gravity.CENTER. In fact, once a new gravity is explicitly set I don't see how one could get it back to the actual default. Also, toasts don't stack for me, they just replace.

Answer (score 171):

If you get an error indicating that you must call makeText, the following code will fix it:

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"Your string here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: makeText returns a Toast object, so you can simply add .addGravity and .show after the makeText.

Comment: _"if you get the error indicating that you must call makeText"_ - when would the error show up?

Comment: The error happens if you use the Constructor so `new Toast(context)` instead of `Toast.makeText(...)`

Answer (score 29):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int)):

***Warning**: Starting from Android Build.VERSION_CODES#R, for apps targeting API level Build.VERSION_CODES#R or higher, this method (**setGravity**) is a no-op when called on text toasts.*

Which means that `setGravity` can no longer be used in API 30+ and will have to find another to achieve the required behaviour.

Comment: `setGravity` doesn't even work well on a lot of devices i testedd it on. I wonder why they keep on changing behaviours of Toasts :(

Comment: `setGravity()` no longer works. Confirmed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: We can't customize the toast anymore, even gravity is also restricted :(

Comment: the toasts setGravity can be set and it works... I did not twaek X, Y co-ordinates, the first parameter works, ex: FILL, VERTICAL etc. etc.  I changed the targetSDKVersion to 32, and it works... so setGravity() is not obsolete..

check the app here: https://github.com/thecyberlab/androidproxyattack, ( you cna tweak the targetSDKVERsion from the code)

Answer (score 17):

You can customize the location of your Toast by using:

`setGravity(int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset)`

[docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setGravity%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

This allows you to be very specific about where you want the location of your Toast to be.

One of the most useful things about the xOffset and yOffset parameters is that you can use them to place the Toast relative to a certain View.

For example, if you want to make a custom Toast that appears on top of a Button, you could create a function like this:

```
// v is the Button view that you want the Toast to appear above 
// and messageId is the id of your string resource for the message

private void displayToastAboveButton(View v, int messageId)
{
    int xOffset = 0;
    int yOffset = 0;
    Rect gvr = new Rect();

    View parent = (View) v.getParent(); 
    int parentHeight = parent.getHeight();

    if (v.getGlobalVisibleRect(gvr)) 
    {       
        View root = v.getRootView();

        int halfWidth = root.getRight() / 2;
        int halfHeight = root.getBottom() / 2;

        int parentCenterX = ((gvr.right - gvr.left) / 2) + gvr.left;

        int parentCenterY = ((gvr.bottom - gvr.top) / 2) + gvr.top;

        if (parentCenterY <= halfHeight) 
        {
            yOffset = -(halfHeight - parentCenterY) - parentHeight;
        }
        else 
        {
            yOffset = (parentCenterY - halfHeight) - parentHeight;
        }

        if (parentCenterX < halfWidth) 
        {         
            xOffset = -(halfWidth - parentCenterX);     
        }   

        if (parentCenterX >= halfWidth) 
        {
            xOffset = parentCenterX - halfWidth;
        }  
    }

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), messageId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, xOffset, yOffset);
    toast.show();       
}
```

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21026866/630833, takes size of Toast into consideration, which was helpful to me.

Comment: This is a great example. Thanks.

Comment: the yOffset and xOffset if/else clauses are redundant as both evaluate to the same thing.

Answer (score 12):

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(test.this,"bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
 toast.show();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Toast mytoast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast Message", 1);  
mytoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);  // for center horizontal
//mytoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);       // for center vertical 
//mytoast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);                       // for top
mytoast.show();
```

The above code is will help u to display toast in the middle of screen or according to ur choice for that just set the toast gravity according to ur need

Note: For this process u have to use object of Toast

Answer (score 3):

The method to change the color, position and background color of toast is:

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is advanced toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT,0,0);
View view=toast.getView();
TextView  view1=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
view1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
toast.show();
```

For line by line explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bzhGd1HZOc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: `getView()` is now deprecated. Custom toast views aren't supported

Answer (score 3):

```
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(test.this,"bbb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

 toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

 toast.show();
```

//this is the best solution to counter any error

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION**

```
fun Context.showToastOnTOP(message: String) = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .apply { setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0); show() }

fun Context.showToastOnBOTTOM(message: String) = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .apply { setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0); show() }
```

Important note `Gravity` will only work if your app target max 29 or less.

Chill Pill :)

Answer (score 2):

//A custom toast class where you can show custom or default toast as desired)

```
public class ToastMessage {
            private Context context;
            private static ToastMessage instance;

            /**
             * @param context
             */
            private ToastMessage(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            /**
             * @param context
             * @return
             */
            public synchronized static ToastMessage getInstance(Context context) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ToastMessage(context);
                }
                return instance;
            }

            /**
             * @param message
             */
            public void showLongMessage(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            /**
             * @param message
             */
            public void showSmallMessage(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            /**
             * The Toast displayed via this method will display it for short period of time
             *
             * @param message
             */
            public void showLongCustomToast(String message) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_toast));
                TextView msgTv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
                msgTv.setText(message);
                Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();


            }

            /**
             * The toast displayed by this class will display it for long period of time
             *
             * @param message
             */
            public void showSmallCustomToast(String message) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_toast, (ViewGroup) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.ll_toast));
                TextView msgTv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
                msgTv.setText(message);
                Toast toast = new Toast(context);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setView(layout);
                toast.show();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Custom toast creation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT,0,0);
    toast.show();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.