# It is possible to specify the position of a Toast?

Tags: android, toast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to change position of Toast in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android)

I have to show a `Toast`, when the user presses a `Button`, but I want to show it a little more down on the `screen`.

How can I do this?

This is the code of my `Toast`:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
getString(R.string.emailregisternotentered),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Solved:

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
getString(R.string.emailregisternotentered), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.emailregisternotentered),
//Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#Positioning

Comment: how can i apply that to my code? i tryed to aply this: "toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);"  but i get an error with no sugestions

Answer (score 2):

[Toast.setGravity](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#setGravity%28int,%20int,%20int%29) is one option.

Comment: how can i apply that to my code? i cant do it, i get an error with no sugestions :S

Comment: What error are you getting? Any exception on logcat?

Comment: solved thanks!!!! check first post for code