# Allignmet and the duration of the Toast?

Tags: android

I want to show the toast always in my application and want to custom alignment of the toast ?

Comment: please clearly specify what you are actually looking for. Toasts are meant for quick messages. What do you mean by "always"?

Comment: [Custom Toast](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-toast-tutorial)
I think this will help you

Comment: Checkout my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537158/how-to-change-the-alignment-of-toast-by-programmatically/7537171#7537171

Answer (score 0):

> want to custom alignment of the toast ?

For changing the alignment you should look at android's official documentation of Toasts : [Custom Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView) or [AndroidPeople--Custom Toasts](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-toast-tutorial)

> I want to show the toast always in my application

For changing the duration of Toast you should look at [Think Android--Indefinite Toast Hack](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/19/indefinite-toast-hack/)