# How to display Toast in different- 2 position

Tags: android

My map activity displaying n number of overlay, when I am tapping on overlay icon then toast is displaying on bottom of screen, But I want to display the Toast near by overlay icon where I am tapping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change position of Toast in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This code is giving me exact position of toast...**
    This code is giving me exact gravity of toast..

```
OverlayItem item = overlayItems_.get(index);
Projection projection = mMapView.getProjection();
    Point point = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(item.getPoint(), point);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, item.getTitle()+" "+item.getSnippet(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, point.x, point.y);
    toast.show();
```

Here i am passing points also..

Answer (score 0):

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
```

Instead of Gravity.TOP you could also use `LEFT` or `RIGHT`

Comment: Thanks to help me, but this solution is giving the gravity of toast to only LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM, but i need toast gravity where ever i am tapping the overlay icon, Now finally i got solution..