# What is a good way to adjust Toast message sizes based on screen size?

Tags: android, toast

I've been using Toast with just the default styles in the apps I'm writing to learn android. It works fine on my rather low resolution phone, but on devices with much higher resolution screens (like my Galaxy Camera), the default Toast messages are microscopically tiny. Is there some standard way to adjust the Toast message font sizes based on screen resolution (or just make it pick font sizes using a point size rather than pixel size)?

Comment: try that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android