# Show Toast above keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, toast

Is it possible to show a Toast message in Android above the keyboard instead of on it when the keyboard is on the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change position of Toast in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android)

Answer (score 9):

You can change toast postion by following code.

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"Your string here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

More than 3 years later... and Android has finally an API

As shown detailed by [Chris Banes](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animating-your-keyboard-fb776a8fb66d) we now can use the `WindowInsets` API

The core API to solve a Toast above soft keyboard are:

```
val insets = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(view) // get insets
val imeVisible = insets.isVisible(Type.ime()) // is keyboard visible?
val imeHeight = insets.getInsets(Type.ime()).bottom // voila, your offset
```

So I build an extension function to Toast:

```
/**
 * Shows toast above soft keyboard, if exists
 */
 fun Toast.showAboveKeyboard(containerView: View) {

   // get y offset to let toast appear above soft keyboard
   val insets = ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets(containerView)
   val imeVisible = insets?.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()) ?: false
   val imeHeight = insets?.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())?.bottom
   val fallbackYOffset = containerView.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.thirtytwo_grid_unit)
   val noSoftKeyboardYOffset =
    containerView.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.three_grid_unit)
   setGravity(
        Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL or Gravity.BOTTOM,
        0,
        if (imeVisible) imeHeight ?: fallbackYOffset else noSoftKeyboardYOffset
   )
   show()
}
```

Usage in a fragment:

```
Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Hello Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
     .showAboveKeyboard(requireView())
```

Happy Toast!

Comment: Hi Alexander. Thanks for this answer. This looks promising :) I'll try to have a look at it and if it works I might change the correct answer here. Not sure when I'll be able to do this, though.