# Positioning a toast with respect to the Screen size

Tags: android

I am displaying a toast in my screen, but the position of the toast appears to vary from device to device, i want the toast to be displayed at one particular position for all the screen sizes.Please help me out with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any one if facing this same problem would suggest you to try this out

**IMP is that you are not in the activity class**

```
  WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
  Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
  Point size = new Point();
  display.getSize(size);
    int width=size.x;
    int height=size.y;
```

where appcontext is ur own appcontext.

---

**but if you are in the activity class you can use this**

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to [get the screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions).

Use them to calculate the toast's position, and [place it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android) in the appropriate position.

Comment: Screen dimensions vary from device to device, so the position is also varying from device to device.

Comment: Which is why I suggested you *get the screen dimensions* first. Check the first link out.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a custom Toast message with a custom xml layout. Refer this [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) on Android Developers.