# Set time appearance for Toast.makeText

Tags: android, android-toast

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.negative), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How do I set a time appearance for this and make this *cancelable*.
Also how do I set this one to appear in the *middle* part of the screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. For time appearance : Duration**

There two cases  : `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` (display in short period of time) or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` (display in long period of time).

You cannot define a time appearance for toasts

**2. Toast gravity : (display in the middle of screen) :**

You can  position the Toast as we desire using a method named setGravity() which has got three parameters: **gravity** , **x-offset** , **y-offset**.

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); // toast in the center of screen
```

**EDIT :**
For your case you can use :

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.positive), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: can you show me the code together with mine.?

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.positive), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); @Ziprox09

Comment: @user3322959 i edit the answer it contains the complete code now

Answer (score 0):

The time the toast is shown is specified here:

```
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
```

in your code. You can only use Toast.LENGTH_SHORT or Toast.LENGTH_LONG ==> Toast is not very flexible with the timing, but they don't need to be, see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html):

> When the view is shown to the user, appears as a floating view over the application. It will never receive focus. The user will probably be in the middle of typing something else. The idea is to be as unobtrusive as possible, while still showing the user the information you want them to see. Two examples are the volume control, and the brief message saying that your settings have been saved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with Toasts. You may want to look a [AlertDialogs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://github.com/SimonVT/MessageBar) library that does almost all the things you requested. It is called MessageBar and is meant to be a replacement for Android's Toast.

As for changing the position of the Toast bar check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507069/616561).