# how to put Toast at center of screen?

Tags: android

In android ,by default toast come in bottom of screen.

```
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How can I place Toast at center of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);`

for further informations
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of existing questions on this. Use `toast.setGravity` function for your purpose. See [How to change position of Toast in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android) 
Eg( taken from one of answers on question):

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
"Your string here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Props for not only referencing the existing question (and giving it credit) but showing the answer from that link. This is how answers should be given ladies and gentleman.