# UI screen design

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an Android application and have to code up the following design for one of the screens:
[image: Android screen]

(Ignore the yellow stuff, I have just masked the Logo and the App-specific information for now)

My question is: How do I design this particular type of screen? The top pane is akin to an ActionBar in Android. However, when any button on the top pane is hit, this custom "popup" having a rectangular form with a small arrow on top pointing towards the button is display and does not interrupt the current/main activity.

I have looked around, but still dont understand how to accomplish this.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: You could still use an ActionBar to display your icons, but when they are hit they show a view over the current layout. Either inflating it at that point or unhiding it from the main layout.

Comment: Thanks for the ActionBar reference. I have implemented the top pane using ActionBar, and currently have a DialogFragment for every menu item click that looks very similar to the design above. But I'm not yet able to have the small arrow that is in the design...any ideas on how to draw that arrow ?

Comment: If you can get the spacing right, you could make a View with a custom shape (or image) background that is the same color as the dialog box. You would figure out the right margin based on which item was selected. With a little trial and error I'm sure you could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native Action Bar along with the icons.

The only problem is if you want to show them all at once.

Some icons may be hidden depending on the size of the phone.

As for the custom pop-up, the toast feature is available to do that.

It is quite easy to adjust the position of toasts and customise toasts :

Customisation of toasts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

Changing postion of toasts: [How to change position of Toast in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android)

Comment: Hi, Your first part about the Action Bar is correct..However the second part is wrong. Toast is used to display Messages alone, and the design above does not lend itself to using toast for the "popup" screen when a actionbar item is selected.