# Android - Customizing Position of Toast Message

Tags: android, eclipse, toast

I have a toast message and the default setting is displaying it bottom-center on the screen. I am wondering how to position it TOP-center. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Official doc : [Android Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) look for `setGravity()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change position of Toast in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android)

Comment: Try to use setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html):

> You can change this position with the setGravity(int, int, int)
>   method. This accepts three parameters: a Gravity constant, an
>   x-position offset, and a y-position offset.
>
> For example, if you decide that the toast should appear in the
>   top-left corner, you can set the gravity like this:
>
> ```
> toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
> ```
>
> If you want to nudge
>   the position to the right, increase the value of the second parameter.
>   To nudge it down, increase the value of the last parameter.

So in your case, you could do:

```
//create toast object
Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), greetings[rndy.nextInt(6)], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//set gravity
myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); //<-- set gravity here
//and show it
myToast.show();
```

Comment: Yes I've read the doc, but I'm unsure of the x and y values to use because I'm thinking they will vary depending on the device that is used?? BTW cool Zoso symbol :) Led Zep!!

Comment: @ub3rfunk: Use values of 0 and 0, but [use `Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#CENTER_HORIZONTAL) instead of `Gravity.LEFT` for horizontal centering.

Comment: Like @CommonsWare said, use 0,0. If you read the last paragraph from the docs aboev, it says that x,y are used to nudge the position = slightly change. Use Gravity flags for general positioning.

Comment: OK. Where do I place the setGravity line of code? Here is my toast message right now: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), greetings[rndy.nextInt(6)], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Many thanks for the help @Melquiades, it's working quite nicely now...cheers

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this a while ago for one of my projects. This places the toast right below whatever view you want it to be. This approach is usually used to override a button's long click to give a short description of what the button does

Below is the button where we want to

```
private View.OnLongClickListener mShareFriendsOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        int offsetY = 10;//getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.toast_offset_y);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.share_with_friends, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ScrapbookUtils.positionToast(toast, v, getWindow(), 0, offsetY);
        toast.show();
        return true;
    }
};
```

And then the actual method that does the work. This utility can make you place your toast wherever you want on your screen.

```
public static void positionToast(Toast toast, View view, Window window, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
    // toasts are positioned relatively to decor view, views relatively to their parents, we have to gather additional data to have a common coordinate system
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    // covert anchor view absolute position to a position which is relative to decor view
    int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
    view.getLocationInWindow(viewLocation);
    int viewLeft = viewLocation[0] - rect.left;
    int viewTop = viewLocation[1] - rect.top;

    // measure toast to center it relatively to the anchor view
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(metrics.widthPixels, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(metrics.heightPixels, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    toast.getView().measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int toastWidth = toast.getView().getMeasuredWidth();

    // compute toast offsets
    int toastX = viewLeft + (view.getWidth() - toastWidth) / 2 + offsetX;
    int toastY = viewTop + view.getHeight() + offsetY;

    toast.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP, toastX, toastY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the simplest way of `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show()`, you can customize your `Toast`. Here is my codes, you can try this:

```
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

If you are still not content, there is a project in `Github` called [`SuperToast`](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts). If you study it, I think you will be inspired a lot.