# Display Toast On Top

Tags: android, toast

I want to show the toast at the top of the screen. 
I am using this, toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);

But on tablet my toast is not being displayed at 0, 0. On phone it is working fine.

[image]

Comment: Check the style for paddings and margins.

Comment: I have checked, no margins no paddings.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to change position of Toast in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android) [(also, documentation source)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Comment: Yes,  you missed something.. I have mentioned that I used toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0); but still the position is not at 0, 0. I thought I missed something that is why posted here.

Comment: Having the same issue :-(

Comment: I am still stuck