# Creating a toast in android and specifying the location

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toast

I am working on my first Android app and I am trying to create a toast and specify the location where I want it to appear. When I was using the code that is now commented (it didn't customize the toast's location) the app ran perfectly on the emulator, but now that I am trying to customize the location and using the code below the comments, the app stops running when I click in the UI on the button meant to show the toast.

Do you have any idea of why this is happening? Because I have seen very similar codes (almost the same) presented as correct, so this should be working. I know this is a very simple code and a simple question, but still, I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.

This is the code on my `onButtonClick`:

```
public void onClick(View V) {

            // Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,
            //                 R.string.correct_toast,
            //                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Toast t = new Toast(QuizActivity.this);
            t.setText(R.string.correct_toast);
            t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
            t.show();

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change position of Toast in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506876/how-to-change-position-of-toast-in-android)

Comment: What your app target API? Why don't you use Snackbar as Toast is kinda phase out nowadays.  Snackbar is used to suit the material design

Comment: @RahulMishra it is not a duplicate if he use the latest android api which result in a different issue

Comment: "_the app stops running when in the UI I click_"  Please post stack trace

Comment: @JohnJoe I just run the app, and right away I have two buttons. Then, when I click on the first of them (which is still using a code like the one on comments) it shows a toast, which is what I am expecting. But then, when I click the other button (which has the code that I modified to make the toast appear in a different place) the app stops running.

Comment: See your log. When your app stops running, threre must be something display on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#Toast(android.content.Context) :

> Construct an empty Toast object. You must call setView(View) before you can call show().

Your code crashes because now you are using the `Toast()` constructor. And you need to `setView(View)` before `show()`. While this is not necessary with `makeText()`.

As I understand, `makeText()` creates a View for you setting the text from the second parameter. But the constructor doesn't, and the `setText()` method does not either. `setText()` only update the an existing text:

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setText(int) :

> Update the text in a Toast that was previously created using one of the makeText() methods.

Here is an example of how to do that:

[Custom toast on Android: a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288475/custom-toast-on-android-a-simple-example)

**Edit**

In any case, you can create the Toast with your initial code, without calling `show()`.

```
public void onClick(View V) {

        Toast t = Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,
                        R.string.correct_toast,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,0,0);
        t.show();

    }
```

**Edit 2**

Now you have edited your code, but you are passing the Button View.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was absolutely helpful. Although even using setView (View) it does not work yet (so I have to further explore this), right now your second suggestion workes perfectly. So, thanks for your help!