# Toast's function: setGravity() - Not changing position

Tags: android, kotlin, toast

I am not receiving any errors.

However, after trying various different variations of gravity and xy offsets, I still cannot get this Toast to budge.

```
val toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP or Gravity.CENTER, 0, 250)
toast.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Instead of 250 replace it with 0 and check it. Can you see?

Comment: I have changed the gravity values as well as the X and Y offset values, nothing changes

Comment: Will toast show if you comment setGravity ? If NOT so maybe you give the wrong context.

Comment: this answer will help you [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507069/14652031

Comment: If you are testing on api 30 [you can't set gravity no more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64349769/15298643)